# Erro status 404 (Servlet)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlet

Estou tendo um problema com essa servlet, quando inicio com o tomcat aparece o erro 404 e aprensenta a seguinte mensagem "The requested resource [/teste/NovaEmpresa] is not available".

JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="NovaEmpresa">
        <label>Nome da empresa:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome"/>
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet

```
package teste;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/NovaEmpresa")
public class NovaEmpresa extends HttpServlet{
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("teste!!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Erro muito comum, podem ser diversas possibilidades. Eu ia pedir mais detalhes (versão do Tomcat, estrutura das pastas, arquivo de configuração) mas talvez esta possa servir como pergunta canônica para o problema. Veja (em inglês): https://stackoverflow.com/q/15545950/2241463

Comment: Quando ele inicia o servidor, tua IDE cria um log, posta o log ai pra gente ver.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu estou vendo ele não está encontrando a página que você está solicitando tente mapear isso no endereço da sua Servlet, por exemplo

```
@WebServlet("/teste/NovaEmpresa")
public class NovaEmpresa extends HttpServlet{
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    {
        System.out.println("teste!!!!");
    }
}
```